# Dynamic action on tab click in Oracle Apex 5

Tags: tabs, oracle-apex

On my page I have a tab container with 2 tabs. Both tabs are filtered by selected list. But one tab not correctly works (custom region) when inactive.

I need to run Dynamic action when specific tab is open. Have you any ideas?

Comment: add a class to the region . create a jquery click event for that class and write the actions. if you want to perform pl/sql commands then inside the jquery call the ondemand process.

Comment: "add a class to the region" you mean static id? can you help me to write jquery selector for custom event?

Comment: i found such example: javascript:apex.jQuery("li[aria-controls='CR_SR_wrhs'] a").trigger("click"); wrhs - is my static ID but it doesn't work

Comment: I can not say if your custom region has some error. Check your custom region has option to add css class(not static id).If yes add a class name(just add a custom name, example: alex ). Then on page load js, write the click event for this class- $( ".alex" ).click(function() {
  // your code
});. I hope this is what you need.

Comment: @Nidheesh Thank you for your advice! You helped me a lot.